# Not able to Release my application in android Market

Tags: android, google-play

can any one guide me to release my application in market?i read all the documents from here:developer.android.com/guide/… and from eclipse i have created certificate still getting error.what is the reason?

Error:

> Market does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create
>   a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.some one is
>   telling me to debug my application in relase mode/what it meant?

Comment: remove debuggable="true" from manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have commented you are getting certificate error while uploading APK to market.

FYI, certificate means KEY in android term.

Let me give you more idea about generating certificates (Key) for the application to be available in android market, basically there are 2 types of certificates to be used:

1. one is for the developer purpose to develop and test application on their device (i.e. Debug Key)
2. second one is PRIVATE Key,

You can generate private key for your android application here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

Here's an example of a Keytool command that generates a private key:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

### Update:

And yes @ingsaurabh has mentioed in comment, remove `android:debuggable="true"` from AndroidManifest.xml if it is there.

Comment: ok thanks to both i have generate key from eclipse and put android:debuggable="false",need it to change any other thing in manifest?

Comment: i think not needed, you can update the application later on if require. so right now just try to upload it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:debuggable="false"` in manifest file. and create a new certificate with validity of 50 year. sign your application using that certificate.